# 'Word' is undefined in office.js Add-in with Word 2013

Tags: vue.js, ms-word, office-js, office-addins

I'm implementing an Office.js Add-in for Word and it works like a charm in MS Word (Windows 10, 1909 & Office 18.2005.1191.0 (that means the add-in runs in the Edge-browser)) and in the browser on office.com (ie11, chrome, edge, ...)

Now the problem: When I switch to a Windows 10 VM with Office 2013 installed, the add-in loads up, and I can use my Vue.js application in the sidebar, but as soon as the add-in calls the office.js interface `await Word.run(...)` an error gets thrown with the message `'Word' is undefined`.

On the same VM, the same `manifest.xml` works perfectly fine on office.com in ie11.

Here is my initialize function:

```
window.Office.initialize = function (reason) {
  new Vue({
    i18n,
    render: h => h(App)
  }).$mount('#app')
}
```

Here is my polyfill:

```
import 'promise-polyfill/src/polyfill'
import 'whatwg-fetch'
```

Here is my script tag from the index.html header

```
<script src="https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/office.js"></script>
```

Any ideas on what to debug next? Definitely possible that I'm missing something basic. Thanks!! <3
[image: Screenshot of sentry.io event]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I think I got it.

Office 2013 isn't compatible with the WordApi 1.1 features I use.

> Perpetual versions of Office support requirement sets as follows:
>
> Office 2019 supports WordApi 1.3 and earlier. Office 2016 only
> supports the WordApi 1.1 requirement set.

[Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/requirement-sets/word-api-requirement-sets)

I will be adding the following lines to my manifest.xml:

```
  <Requirements>
  <Sets DefaultMinVersion="1.1">
    <Set Name="WordApi" MinVersion="1.1" />
  </Sets>
</Requirements>
...
```

Comment: Can you put the full manifest, or at least explain where we put these lines? Because I don't see any of these tags in my manifest.